Any way access private and secure network remotely?
I have a home network setup with its own infrastructure, along with several servers in data centers for VPN, backup, and other purposes. I'm looking to create a secure network between them that allows me to access any of the servers from any internet connection. I also want to connect my personal devices (like my laptop and mobile phone) as peers and use some of the servers as exit nodes.
I've tried services like Tailscale, Netbird, and Twingate, but some of my servers are in regions with geo-restricted networks, which prevents them from establishing the initial connection to these services for login.
I'm looking for either a method to resolve this issue with these services or alternative solutions that don't have geo-restriction problems.

If the locations are known on beforehand and won't change and are not that many, you can create a VPN tunnel between the sites. This essentially makes all locations part of the same network. It is not a solution where you can access this network from anywhere in the world though, but if you have a VPN server at home that you VPN into from anywhere in the world, you can then access the larger network through there.

you need to more clearly describe this part: "but some of my servers are in regions with geo-restricted networks, which prevents them from establishing the initial connection to these services for login." are you talking about nation-state firewalls like china/saudia arabia?

Direct satellite relay could work around national restrictions, until the Федеральная служба безопасности Российской Федерации, اِسلامیِ ایران, or whatever come by to compliment your ingenuity.

@FrankThomas Yeah, exactly some of my servers are in locations where those services are denied to give services or governments blocked access.

Specifically for Tailscale, there exists a self-hostable version of its controller: headscale. If you have at least one server which is accessible from all other servers, you can use it as your Tailscale controller.
For internal access, it is possible to build such a network by hand:

Create a ton of GRE or L2TP or WireGuard tunnels between your servers, e.g. each server having one link to a nearby server plus one backup link to somewhere else.
Enable IP routing on all servers (between the tunnel interfaces).
Run OSPF or Babel over those tunnels and let it figure out paths to each node.

As long as every server can reach at least one another server, the routing protocol will automatically make sure that the rest of the network will be able to reach it as well. Any of those servers can act as an entry point into the rest of the network (using whichever client VPN protocol you want).
(For OSPF-over-WireGuard you will want individual 0.0.0.0/0 interfaces, one for each peer; not just a single multi-peer interface. For GRE or L2TP you'd want transport-mode IPsec underneath to provide encryption. Route-based IPsec tunnels might also work.)
This lets you SSH into any machine that's part of the network (and of course use that machine as a proxy using ssh -D); it however doesn't really make it easy to use a given server as an "exit node" for general IP traffic. For that you'd preferably need a "layer 2" mesh VPN like Tinc (in 'switch' mode). Possibly ZeroTier might also work but I don't think it has full mesh routing, relying on dedicated relays instead.
The network doesn't have to be homogeneous; you can mix WireGuard, OpenVPN, dial-up, etc. as long as it can carry OSPF (or Babel) routing protocol packets, and you probably can add Headscale into the mix with static routes to/from.
